# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to make a discord music bot and i have to admit that i dont have much knowledge on javascript so im just following a tutorial. Now this is the code he wrote

```json
const slashFiles = fs.readdirSync("./slash").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))
for (const file of slashFiles){
    const slashcmd = require(`./slash/${file}`)
    client.toLocaleLowerCase.set(slashcmd.data.name, slashcmd)
    if (LOAD_SLASH) commands.push(slashcmd.data.toJSON())
}
```

and thats the error im getting

```json
 client.toLocaleLowerCase.set(slashcmd.data.name, slashcmd)
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stelj\Desktop\bot\main.js:31:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Pls help

Comment: What do you expect `client.toLocaleLowerCase` to be and why?  The name `toLocaleLowerCase` sounds like a function, which you've forgotten to invoke (using `()` after it).  But it also sounds like a function that would return *a string*, so it's not clear what is intended by calling `.set()` on that string.

Comment: @Lliakos What exactly fixed your error?

Comment: @K.KDesgins i didnt fix it, i threw the hole thing in the trash and just started from the start